# OpenBSD 5.8 New User Error

Tags: openbsd

When I try to create a new user I get an error on OpenBSD 5.8

`# useradd -m foo`

`bin/pax: invalid option -- 'e'
Try 'pax --help' or 'pax --usage' for more information.
useradd: [Warning] can't system`cd /etc/skel && /bin/pax -rw -pe  . /home/foo'`

It looks like it is creating the user, but it is not populating the home directory with the needed skeleton files.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend doing it like this:

```
# useradd -k /etc/skel/ -s /bin/ksh -G wheel,operator -m foo
```

(without being in wheel or at least operator groups you almost do not exist)

or using the built in script:

```
# adduser
```